# Xcode lost connection with simulator iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, ios9

I'm using `xcode Version 7.0`, When i run the app using iOS9 simulator, it always throws the following error

`The operation couldn’t be completed. (FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain error 1.)`

Its very annoying, Any Suggestions !
Thanks.

Comment: Are you using any third-party libraries ?

Comment: Yes I am, I'm not sure if its related to third-party libraries

Comment: I'm not sure whether it is correct or not. I've two different projects, in one of them I'm using FaceBook SDK, in which I'm getting the same issue. But on the other one no issues (which doesn't have any third-party sdk)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is seems to be cause by [App Transport Security](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/).

Please follow the [steps](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9) provided by the FB team in order to get their SDK working on iOS 9.

I am not sure if you are using other SDK also then you need to make sure its according to ATS.